# MailboxProcessor and interaction with GUI Thread

Tags: multithreading, f#, mailboxprocessor

I've created an agent interacting with GUI by means of SynchronizationContext:

```
type AsyncWorker(id:int) =
    let someEvent = new Event<int * string>()
    let errorEvent = new Event<_>()
    let syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

    let f (inbox: MailboxProcessor<_>)  = 
        let rec loop () = async {        
            let! message = inbox.Receive ()
            ...
            syncContext.RaiseEvent someEvent (id, str)
        }
```

Is there any danger in that? What if I had 20 agents? Are these raised events synchronized? Suppose I have some long time calculating function for this event. Can I be sure that the other agents' event handlers will be waiting for its termination?

Comment: You need to make sure that the agents are created on a thread where the `SynchronizationContext` is valid, e.g. a WinForms or a WPF thread. If you create an agent on the threadpool, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be null.

Comment: @MisterMetaphor. Yes, of course the agents are created in the GUI thread.